# In R, use dplyr's mutate() to create a new variable conditional on contents of another

Tags: r

I would like to search the contents of one variable, `placement`, and create a new variable, `term`, based on the pattern sought. A minimal example...

First I create a search pattern function:

```
calcterm <- function(x){    # calcterm takes a column argument to read
    print(x)
    if (x %in% '_fa_') {
            return ('fall')
    } else if (x %in% '_wi_') {
            return('winter')
    } else if (x %in% '_sp_') {
            return('spring')
    } else {return('summer')
    }
}
```

I'll create a small data frame, which I'll then pass to dplyr's `tbl_df`:

```
placement <- c('pn_ds_ms_fa_th_hrs','pn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs' ,'pn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs')
hours <- c(1230, NA, 34)

d <- data.frame(placement, hours)

library(dplyr)

d <- tbl_df(d)
```

Table d now appears as:

```
>d
    Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

       placement hours
          (fctr) (dbl)
1 pn_ds_ms_fa_th_hrs  1230
2 pn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs    NA
3 pn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs    34
```

Next, I use mutate to implement my function. The goal is to read the contents of `placement`, and create a new variable, that will result in a value of either `fall`, `winter`, `spring`, or `summer` depending a pattern found within the `placement` column.

```
d %>% mutate(term=calcterm(placement))
```

The output leaves me with

```
[1] pn_ds_ms_fa_th_hrs pn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs pn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs
Levels: pn_ds_ms_fa_th_hrs pn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

       placement hours   term
          (fctr) (dbl)  (chr)
1 pn_ds_ms_fa_th_hrs  1230 summer
2 pn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs    NA summer
3 pn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs    34 summer

Warning messages:
    1: In if (x %in% "_fa_") { :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
    2: In if (x %in% "_wi_") { :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
    3: In if (x %in% "_sp_") { :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

So, clearly I've written something wrong in the very beginning... Perhaps the `%in%` could be swapped for a grep pattern? I'm not sure how to approach that.

Thanks.

## **UPDATE**

Based on response below, I'm updating this with my full series of pipes to show how I am implementing this. The data I'm working with is "wide" and I'm starting by just flipping it's axis, and extracting the useful information from the colnames. This example works --- but in my own data, when I get to the mutate() step, I'm getting the message: `Error: invalid subscript type 'list'`

Worth noting, after summarise() I get the warning:

```
Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped
```

Perhaps this has something to do with the next step failing? Since the warning does not appear in my example?

```
set.seed(1) 

dfmaker <- function() {
        setNames(
                data.frame(
                        replicate(5, sample(c(NA, 300:500), 4, TRUE), FALSE)), 
                c('pn_ds_ms_fa_th_hrs','rn_ds_ms_wi_th_stu' ,'adn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs','pn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs' ,'rn_bsn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs'))
}


d <- dfmaker()

library(dplyr)

d <- tbl_df(d)

grepl_vec_pattern = Vectorize(grepl, 'pattern')

calcterm = function(s) {
        require(pryr)
        s = as.character(s)
        grepped_patterns = grepl_vec_pattern(s, pattern = c('_sp', '_su', '_fa', '_wi'))
        stopifnot(any(rowSums(grepped_patterns) == 1))   # Ensure that there is exactly one match
        reduce_to_colname_with_true = apply(grepped_patterns, 1, compose(names, which))
        lut_table = c('_sp' = 'spring', '_su' = 'summer', '_fa' = 'fall', '_wi' = 'winter')
        lut_table[reduce_to_colname_with_true]
}

select(d, matches("^pn_|^adn_|^bsn_"), -starts_with("rn_bsn")) %>%  # all the pn, adn, bsn programs, for all information 
        select(contains("_hrs") ) %>%   # takes out just the hours
        gather(placement, hours) %>%  # flip it!
        group_by(placement) %>%  # gather all the schools into a single observation (replicated placement values at this point)
        summarise(sumHours = sum(hours, na.rm=T)) %>%
        mutate(term = calcterm(placement))
```

Comment: `%in%` is for exact match to regex. And `mutate` doesn't do anything special which can't be done in base R so no need for `dplyr` at all in this operation.

Comment: You can also do all these operations in Excel, which does not automatically mean you shouldn't use R. The OP asks a question how to do stuff in `dplyr`, answer the question or don't answer the question. This is a perfectly valid use for `dplyr`.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra the title of this question is "*use dplyr's mutate() in order... etc.*", not "*How to find matches..., etc.*". All I was trying to say is that in order to solve the problem, you shouldn't focus on how to use `dplyr::mutate` (the specific tool) as there is nothing special about, rather should try to focus on the problem itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple and very efficient way could be to create a simple lookup/patterns vectors and then combine (the very efficient) `stringi::stri_detect_fixed` with `data.table`. This solution should scale very well even for huge data sets

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table)
Lookup <- c("fall", "winter", "spring")
Patterns <- c("fa", "wi", "sp")
setDT(d)[, term := Lookup[stri_detect_fixed(placement, Patterns)], by = placement]
d[is.na(term), term := "summer"]
d
#             placement hours   term
# 1: pn_ds_ms_fa_th_hrs  1230   fall
# 2: pn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs    NA winter
# 3: pn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs    34 winter
```

---

If we insist on `dplyr`, we will need to create an helper function to handle situations when no match was found (something that `data.table` habdles automatically)

```
f <- function(x, Lookup, Patterns) {
  temp <- Lookup[stri_detect_fixed(x[1L], Patterns)]
  if(!length(temp)) return("summer")
  temp
}

d %>%
  group_by(placement) %>%
  mutate(term = f(placement, Lookup, Patterns))

# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# Groups: placement [2]
# 
#           placement hours   term
#               (fctr) (dbl)  (chr)
# 1 pn_ds_ms_fa_th_hrs  1230   fall
# 2 pn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs    NA winter
# 3 pn_ds_ms_wi_th_hrs    34 winter
```

Comment: A very neat and concise solution. You could however perform the lookup in base R and skip using an external package such as `data.table` ;).

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I can't because `grepl` won't accept more than one pattern unless I will use the `|` operator between them. In that case, I won't be able to use `fixed  = TRUE` and lose *a lot* of speed. I've been using this solution in real life and found `stri_detect_fixed` to be absolutely brilliant for both convenience and unbelievable speed.

Comment: Ok, fair ehough. It was also more of a jab at your bashing the use of `dplyr` consistently :). Again, nice solution +1.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra fair enough, though as per the link to my Meta answer in the mentioned discussion, I won't use packages if I don't need them. In this case I used `data.table` because of the `by` operations and haven't used `dplyr` because `mutate` can't handle a "no match" and always expects an input.

Comment: @DavidArenburg great suggestion. This does look efficient and scales well - I might change my workflow to implement this before I start using the dplyr functions. I posed this as a mutate question originally because my piping workflow wasn't broken using only dyplyr.

Comment: @M.Elliott OK, I wrote a small helper function that will work with `dplyr` too, see edit.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Just saw this update - thanks for the addition; very nice. Again, I run into the same issue as with the other solution posted here, so I'll backup and either implement your first suggestion, or start a new post trying to better understand why i'm getting the 'Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped'

Comment: My `dplyr` version doesn't work for you? Did you copy the function one by one? You should make sure `x[1L]` is present, otherwise it will grab too many values.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you cannot put a logical vector in an `if` statement. The response from R will be to only use the first element in the logical vector, and throw the warning message you got.

To solve this, I will be using `grepl`. First, let's create some example data:

```
s = c('bla_wi', 'spam_sp', 'egg_sp', 'ham_fa')
```

Next we need to realize that you cannot pass multiple search patterns to `grepl`. Luckily, we can solve that by vectorizing `grepl` in the `pattern` argument:

```
grepl_vec_pattern = Vectorize(grepl, 'pattern')
grepped_patterns = grepl_vec_pattern(s, pattern = c('_sp', '_su', '_fa', '_wi'))
grepped_patterns
#        _sp   _su   _fa   _wi
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Each column in `grepped_patterns` expresses if the pattern passed matched.

Next we want to reduce this to a vector which lists which pattern matched to that element (assuming that only one pattern matched obviously):

```
library(pryr)
reduce_to_colname_with_true = apply(grepped_patterns, 1, compose(names, which))
reduce_to_colname_with_true
# [1] "_wi" "_sp" "_sp" "_fa"
```

Note that `compose(A, B)` equals `A(B())`, i.e. calling the function nested. I chose to use `compose` to prevent using an anonymous function like: `function(x) names(which(x))`.

Now we have this information, we need to translate `_sp` to `spring` etc:

```
lut_table = c('_sp' = 'spring', '_su' = 'summer', '_fa' = 'fall', '_wi' = 'winter')
lut_table[reduce_to_colname_with_true]
#      _wi      _sp      _sp      _fa 
# "winter" "spring" "spring"   "fall"
```

and we have the required result. To use this in `mutate`, we can wrap this all in a function:

```
calcterm = function(s) {
    require(pryr)
    s = as.character(s)
    grepped_patterns = grepl_vec_pattern(s, pattern = c('_sp', '_su', '_fa', '_wi'))
    stopifnot(any(rowSums(grepped_patterns) == 1))   # Ensure that there is exactly one match
    reduce_to_colname_with_true = apply(grepped_patterns, 1, compose(names, which))
    lut_table = c('_sp' = 'spring', '_su' = 'summer', '_fa' = 'fall', '_wi' = 'winter')
    lut_table[reduce_to_colname_with_true]
}
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(s = s) %>% mutate(term = calcterm(s))
df
        s   term
1  bla_wi winter
2 spam_sp spring
3  egg_sp spring
4  ham_fa   fall
```

Comment: Ah - I forgot about lut! Yes!! Thank you, this is very helpful! Although I might actually implement the method posed by @DavidArenburg in some situations (perhaps this one), you are spot on - I really wanted to see how this would come together using the tools I specified. Learning different methods and how/why they work helps me make more efficient decisions in the future.

Comment: do I need to place `grepl_vec_pattern = Vectorize(grepl, 'pattern')` inside the calcterm function as well?

Comment: @melliot it is not needed. If you place it outside the function in the global environment, it will be found.

Comment: I'm getting the following, 'Error: invalid subscript type 'list'`
`In addition: Warning message:`
`attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped` ...

Comment: You'll have to post a reproducible example, it is hard to provide any feedback without it...

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry about that. In creating my example, the function works perfectly, and I'll add the full pipeline of what I'm doing to the post... However, it does not work on my real data, and I cannot see why... This example is the closest thing I can do to replicate what I'm actually working on, so I just have to keep searching for what is different!